# Splitting a SQL insert from PHPmyAdmin to Adminer

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, dump

I am trying to move my database to another server.

My Adminer has a 2MB SQL max dump (upload) limit.
I currently have one table that is about 10MB big.

I was wondering what approaches I can take to split this 10MB table (or modify the dump file) in order to import it via Adminer.

Comment: What sort of unique key does this big table have? The best approach is to get chunks of that table, but it would be useful to know how to split it up.

Comment: The table's unique key are just the ID. The data within the table are pages. Each pages comes from a book, so I have about 5,000 books within the database which may be approximately about 100,000+ pages.

Answer (score 10):

There are following options:

- Upload the file by FTP as `adminer.sql` (or `adminer.sql.gz`) and then run it [from server](http://www.adminer.org/static/screenshots/sql.png).
- Gzip or Bzip2 the file - maybe it can squeeze in 2 MB.
- Increase the PHP limit - `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.
- Export the table by parts - limit the result set and export it from [select](http://www.adminer.org/static/screenshots/select.png).

Comment: @Anraiki - the last option here is the one I was thinking of. Export the table in groups of 1000 books.

Comment: @Jakub Vrána Could you add the path where Adminer finds the adminder.sql file? I cant determine it and adminer always gives me a "file not found" error. Is it the webroot? the same directory as adminer is installed?

Comment: It's the same directory where Adminer is.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : **Adminer: to increase limit for import**

```
/etc/php/5.6/apache2$ *sudo vim php.ini*

upload_max_filesize = 200M // 2M originally

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Good solution! It's been 8 years since I asked this question and if you have SSH with admin capabilities, it would be easier to do a SQL DUMP allowing you to skip configuration and also timeout execution restriction that PHP may have.

Answer (score 1):

If your database.sql.gz file is on server or anywhere else, you can import it using the following method.

```
$ zcat import_file.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -p database_name
```

It will ask you for your SQL password, just entered it, and then you're done. If database_name flash the error then just create manually database_name in your "adminer" then import. It will work 100% sure.